# Errors when migrating from maven to gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, migrating

Hi I was trying to migrate from maven to gradle, but I have this error when compiling, and I'm pretty new to gradle so idk now how exactly to fix things and where to fix them.
I cannot share the src bc its private, but i can share some img if needed of the project.

```
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Entry org/lydark/api/common/Api.class is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to understand how your Jar task is configured.  It seems you have more than one `org.lydark.api.common.Api` class.  I think that is only possibly if you have multiple source sets, but without knowing your project structure I can't say exactly.  You can't share the project but can you share just the `build.gradle` file?

IF you can identify and eliminate the extra Api class then your problem should go away.  If you can't solve that, as a workaround (not a proper solution), you can configure the duplicate handling for the Jar task.
E.g.:

```
jar {
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

See the documentation pointed to by the error for more information.

Based on your additional information...
Why can't it be in a separate module? You should make three nested projects. Api, Api-Spigot, Api-Velocity.  Api-Spigot and Api-Velocity will depend on Api.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

Comment: Hi yes, I do, I have it duplicated, because I had 3 modules: 
Api -> The common classes.
Api-Spigot -> Where there are specific dependencies and even a different Java version
Api-Velocity -> Where there are other dependencies that can't work with the last module.
So why did I pasted the common src of the Api in all the modules, just because when I want to deploy each Api-Spigot and Api-Velocity, it need this files to be or in a repository, or locally, but it can't be in a different module, at least with maven I couldn't deploy it like that.

Comment: See my recent edit to the answer.  You should make three sub-projects.